# What is an Identity operator wrt to argument of a vector function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

In Principles of Quantum Mechanics by R. Shankar at page 326 he asked to show that (Excercise 12.5.1)

$\begin{bmatrix}
{\psi}_x\\{\psi}_y\\\end{bmatrix} =\left(\ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix} -\frac{i\epsilon_z}{\hbar}\begin{bmatrix}L_z & 0\\0 & L_z\\\end{bmatrix}- \frac{i\epsilon_z}{\hbar}\begin{bmatrix}0 & -i\hbar\\i\hbar & 0\\\end{bmatrix}\right)$

or, $J_z=L_z^{(1)}\otimes{I^{(2)}} + I^{(1)}\otimes{S_z^{(2)}}$

Where Shankar said $I^{(1)}$ is the identity operator with respect to the argument of the vector function $\pmb\Psi(x,y)$.
The problem is what is and Identity operator w.r.t Argument of a function?
How to find it?
I'm stuck here and can't go forward. So, please help me.

> He asked to show that to rotate a vector function we need two operators, one for rotating the components of the vector and other for reassingning the vector at new point.

Comment: An identity operator is an operator that does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The operator $I^{(1)}$ is just the multiplication by $1$
acting on a position-dependent function $f(x,y)$.

And the operator $I^{(2)}$ is the multiplication by
the unity matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$
acting on a 2-component vector
$\begin{bmatrix}f_x\\f_y\end{bmatrix}$.